# react-stripe-elements v1.1.0 createPaymentMethod not working in react 15.6.2

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Im trying to integrate createPaymentMethod of stripe using react-stripe-elements in react 15.6.2 project. I'm able to see card element on UI but after filling all card details Im getting 400 Bad request error with following response

**"error": {
"message": "You cannot attach a PaymentMethod to a Customer during PaymentMethod creation. Please instead create the PaymentMethod and then attach it using the attachment method of the PaymentMethods API.",
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}**

here is my code

```
render() {
const styles = require("./CheckoutForm.scss");

return (
  <div className={styles.CheckoutForm}>
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className={""}>
      <label>
        Card details
        <CardElement style={{ base: { fontSize: "18px" } }} />
      </label>
      <Button bsStyle="success" type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
        <FormattedMessage id="Action.Pay" />
      </Button>
      <Button bsStyle="default" type="button" className="btn-danger" onClick={this.onCancel}>
        <FormattedMessage id="Action.Cancel" />
      </Button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

}

and onClick Im doing like this -

```
onSubmit = ev => {
ev.preventDefault();
alert(1);
const cardElement = this.props.stripe.elements("card");
this.props.stripe
  .createPaymentMethod({
    type: "card",
    card: cardElement,       
    billing_details: { name: "Jenny Rosen" }
  })
  .then(({ paymentMethod }) => {
    /*eslint-disable */
    console.log("Received Stripe PaymentMethod:", paymentMethod);
    /*eslint-enable */
  });
```

};

**Note -** react:15.6.2 , react-stripe-elements: 1.1.0. I cant update react and react-stripe-elements

What should I have to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect you have code running somewhere that is trying to specify a customer ID when creating the PaymentMethod. If that doesn't help, I suggest reaching out to Stripe support directly who will be able to tell you more about that error message: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: No i don't have such code